# Spawn a gameobject from list when grip button is clicked?

Tags: unity, spawning

I wanted to spawn gameobjects from the list one by one when the grip button in the controller is clicked. I have attached my code [image: Code to instantiate object when grip is clicked] and the inspector [image: inspector] which contains the list of gameobject but the code is not working. Need Help

Comment: At first you must check your DoGripClicked function in a simple way. For example paste Debug.Log("Hello world") code into your function.

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as images. Include a complete description of what specifically is not working: are you getting a compilation or runtime error? Is the function not getting called? Is it called but failing to have the desired effect? What does it do instead, if anything?

Comment: It looks like you've posted a copy of this question with a different initiation condition and a better code example. Since that version has an answer already, I'll close this older one as a duplicate. In future, to refine a question based on feedback or evolving needs, please use the edit button instead of posting a new separate question.